# ROS2 python launch: Using argument to create file name for a launch_argument

Tags: ros, python, ros2, roslaunch, parameter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I like to launch gazebo with different environments (world files). But I only want to give as argument the world file name and not the full path. The full path should be created by launch file.

How can I use a `LaunchArgument` to create a full file name. The following statement in the `IncludeLaunchDescription` is not working.

```
launch_arguments={'world': pkg_tuw_gazebo + '/worlds/' + LaunchConfiguration('room') + '.world'}.items(),
```

Thanks in advance

There's the full code python launch file.

```
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.actions import SetEnvironmentVariable
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.actions import SetEnvironmentVariable
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, TextSubstitution 

def generate_launch_description():

    room_arg    = DeclareLaunchArgument('room', default_value=TextSubstitution(text='roblab'))
    pkg_gazebo_ros = get_package_share_directory('gazebo_ros')
    pkg_tuw_gazebo = get_package_share_directory('tuw_gazebo')
    pkg_tuw_gazebo_models = get_package_share_directory('tuw_gazebo_models')

    if 'GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH' in os.environ:
        model_path =  os.environ['GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH'] \
            + ':' + pkg_tuw_gazebo_models + '/models'
    else:
        model_path =  pkg_tuw_gazebo_models + '/models'

    return LaunchDescription([
        room_arg,
        SetEnvironmentVariable(name='GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH', value=model_path),
        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource( os.path.join(pkg_gazebo_ros, 'launch', 'gazebo.launch.py')),
            # This is working, but I like to substitute cave in cave.world with my argument
            #launch_arguments={'world': os.path.join(pkg_tuw_gazebo, 'worlds', 'cave.world')}.items(),  
            # This is NOT working, I don't know how to access the room argument?
            launch_arguments={'world': pkg_tuw_gazebo + '/worlds/' \
                + LaunchConfiguration('room') + '.world'}.items(),
        ) 
    ])
```

I am getting the Error:

```
launch.invalid_launch_file_error.InvalidLaunchFileError: Caught exception when trying to load file of format [py]: can only concatenate str (not "LaunchConfiguration") to str
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404041/ros2-python-launch:-using-argument-to-create-file-name-for-a-launch_argument/) by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on ROS Answers with karma: 847 on 2022-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use `OpaqueFunction` for this, nice example is there:

- https://github.com/ros-drivers/urg_node/blob/foxy-devel/launch/urg_node_launch.py

Or in this accepted answer:

- https://answers.ros.org/question/382028/ros2-string-repr-of-parameter-within-launch-file/

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2022-07-22**:
Thanks, I found now a way by using `OpaqueFunction`.

My solution looks now like:

```
def generate_launch_description():

    ...
    ...

    def world_file_file_name(context):
        file = os.path.join(pkg_tuw_gazebo, 'worlds', context.launch_configurations['room'] + '.world')
        return [SetLaunchConfiguration('world', file)]

    world_file_path_arg = OpaqueFunction(function=world_file_file_name)

    return LaunchDescription([
        DeclareLaunchArgument('room', default_value=TextSubstitution(text='empty')),
        world_file_path_arg,
        SetEnvironmentVariable(name='GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH', value=model_path),
        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource( os.path.join(pkg_gazebo_ros, 'launch', 'gazebo.launch.py')),
        ) 
    ])
```

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-07-22**:
Nice, please accept the answer, if it explains everything, so it is properly marked in the queue :)